# ASP.net MVC fire controller event when view load

Tags: asp.net

I'm using ASP.net MVC and angular js to create a web. I used angular ng-route to render a View when click a link. The moment when render the View, i want fire the Controller event in order to bind the data and display it. (Similar with ASP.net web form, when page load then can call the data binding function). 
I'm new in MVC, hope can get some help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using MVC, it would be better if you use the `return View();` statement on a Controller, and it would render the view that you want.

Here's a sample:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/806029/Getting-started-with-AngularJS-and-ASP-NET-MVC-Par